# Ruby: Objects currently instantiated

Tags: ruby, object

1. Is there a way to get a list of all currently instantiated objects?
2. Can that list be made to send an event/message asynchronously whenever it changes?

Comment: This set of tasks makes me want to cry... I hope it is merely as a debugging/diagnostic aide.

Comment: for #2, create a new thread in your irb and delegate the watch of your attributes

Answer (score 4):

The [ObjectSpace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/ObjectSpace.html) module contains a number of routines that interact with the garbage collection facility and allow you to traverse all living objects with an iterator.

```
ObjectSpace.count_objects
# => {:TOTAL=>56824, :FREE=>7190, :T_OBJECT=>5943, :T_CLASS=>878, :T_MODULE=>35, :T_FLOAT=>7, :T_STRING=>26950, :T_REGEXP=>189, :T_ARRAY=>10224, :T_HASH=>193, :T_STRUCT=>1, :T_BIGNUM=>5, :T_FILE=>7, :T_DATA=>1674, :T_MATCH=>22, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_NODE=>3468, :T_ICLASS=>37}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ObjectSpace](http://apidock.com/ruby/ObjectSpace) is your friend; not sure about #2.